# How to get MAC address of bluetooth HID device?

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, hid

how can I get the MAC address of a bluetooth device which connected as HID device?

I have handle to the device

```
Handle = CreateFile(didetail->DevicePath, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

but I can't find how to get the MAC address.

C++; Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I was going to say you should pipe the results of ipconfig/all into a file, but then I found this:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/networkinformation/article.php/c5451/Three-ways-to-get-your-MAC-address.htm

Scroll halfway down to GetAdaptersInfo, that should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Unless I missed something, I feel like this doesn't actually answer the original question.  This solution talks about finding the MAC address of local network adapters.  The question, however, asks about the address of a remote Bluetooth device.